# file already in use exception after using dispose and SuppressFinalize on MS access File

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbconnection

I am working on software that make changes in database through GUI. I want to compact database after user clicks save. After save user can continue to use software or close, so I am not using "using". I have created databaseAccess object which holds OleDbConnection connection object with few others. This is my database access class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeTool
{
    public class DataBaseAccess
    {
        #region Properties
        private string m_directory;
        public List<string> selectedTableNames;
        private Dictionary<String, DataTable> selectedTables;
        private OleDbConnection mdbConnection;
        DataTable dataTable;

        //Constructor
        public DataBaseAccess()
        {
            selectedTableNames = new List<string>();
            selectedTables = new Dictionary<string, DataTable>();
        }

        public string directory
        {
            get
            {
                return m_directory;
            }
            set
            {
                m_directory = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        public List<string> GetAllTableNames()
        {
            if (dataTable != null)
            {
                List<string> tableList = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string TableName = dataTable.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                    tableList.Add(TableName);
                }
                return tableList;
            }
            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns Table Columns
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public DataTable GetTable(string TableName)
        {
            DataTable mdbTable;
            if (selectedTables.TryGetValue(TableName, out mdbTable))
            {
                return mdbTable;
            }
            else
            {
                mdbTable = new DataTable();
                //mdbConnection.Open();
                string mdbCommandString = "SELECT * FROM [" + TableName + "]";
                OleDbDataAdapter QueryCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(mdbCommandString, mdbConnection);
                QueryCommand.Fill(mdbTable);
                //mdbConnection.Close();

                selectedTables.Add(TableName, mdbTable);

                return mdbTable;
            }
        }

        public void SetTable(String TableName, DataTable dataTable)
        {
            //mdbConnection.Open();

            OleDbCommand ac = new OleDbCommand("delete from [" + TableName + "]", mdbConnection);
            ac.ExecuteNonQuery();

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                String query = "INSERT INTO [" + TableName + "] (TaskID, HTMLTopic, nRelative, [Group], nKey,"
                    + " [nText], nImage, nSelImage, nFontName, nFontInfo, Keywords) VALUES (@TaskID,"
                    + " @HTMLTopic, @nRelative, @Group, @nKey, @nText, @nImage, @nSelImage, @nFontName, "
                    + " @nFontInfo, @Keywords)";
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, mdbConnection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskID", row["TaskID"]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HTMLTopic", row["HTMLTopic"]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nRelative", row["nRelative"]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group", row["Group"]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nKey", row["nKey"]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nText", row["nText"]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nImage", row["nImage"]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nSelImage", row["nSelImage"]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nFontName", row["nFontName"]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nFontInfo", row["nFontInfo"]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Keywords", row["Keywords"]);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            //mdbConnection.Close();
        }

        internal bool validTable(string TableName)
        {
            DataTable mdbTable = new DataTable();

            //mdbConnection.Open();

            string mdbCommandString = "SELECT * FROM [" + TableName + "]";
            OleDbDataAdapter QueryCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(mdbCommandString, mdbConnection);
            QueryCommand.Fill(mdbTable);
            //mdbConnection.Close();

            // check if table contains all columns necessary
            String[] columnNames = new string[] { "TaskID" , "HTMLTopic", "nRelative", "Group", "nKey",
                "nText", "nImage", "nSelImage", "nFontName", "nFontInfo", "Keywords"};

            Boolean missingColumn = false;

            DataColumnCollection columns = mdbTable.Columns;
            foreach (String columnName in columnNames)
            {
                if (columns.Contains(columnName) == false)
                {
                    // print the message
                    MessageBox.Show("Database: " + directory + " Table: " + TableName + " is missing column \"" + columnName
                        + "\". Add it to make changes.",
                        "Missing column",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                    missingColumn = true;
                }
            }

            if (missingColumn == true)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void insertTable(String tableName)
        {
            selectedTableNames.Add(tableName);
        }

        public List<String> getSelectedTables()
        {
            return selectedTableNames;
        }

        public Boolean isConnected()
        {
            if (mdbConnection == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void connect()
        {
            if (mdbConnection == null)
            {
                String m_mdbDirectory = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + m_directory;
                mdbConnection = new OleDbConnection(m_mdbDirectory);
                mdbConnection.Open();
                string[] restrictions = new string[4];
                restrictions[3] = "Table";
                dataTable = mdbConnection.GetSchema("TABLES", restrictions);
                //mdbConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        public void disconnect()
        {
            mdbConnection.Close();
            mdbConnection.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(mdbConnection);
            mdbConnection = null;
        }

        public void clearSelectedTables()
        {
            selectedTableNames.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Save and compact functions are like this

```
    private void save()
    {   
        foreach(DataBaseAccess database in databases)
        {
            // save changes code
            database.disconnect();
            CompactAndRepairAccessDB(database.directory);
            database.connect();
        }
    }

    private void CompactAndRepairAccessDB(string accessFile)
    {
        string tempFile = @"temp.mdb";
        FileInfo temp = new FileInfo(tempFile);

        // Required COM reference for project:
        // Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
        var dbe = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine();
        try
        {
            dbe.CompactDatabase(accessFile, tempFile);
            temp.CopyTo(accessFile, true);
            temp.Delete();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

The exception happens on line "dbe.CompactDatabase(accessFile, tempFile);".

Comment: At which part of the Code the error occurs?

Comment: dbe.CompactDatabase(accessFile, tempFile);

Comment: Why do you use `GC.SuppressFinalize`? Why do you want the Finalizer not to be called?

Comment: Why do the `connect()` call `mdbConnection.Close();` and the `disconnect()` too? After commenting the  `mdbConnection.Close();` out in the connect function, everything works fine for me.

Comment: @Rinecamo After calling Dispose, you must release all references to the Component so the garbage collector can reclaim the memory that the Component was occupying.

Comment: Please have a look at Line 82: http://pastebin.com/scLQwYQp

Comment: @smartis It did not work in my case, I have updated question to reflect complete class.

Comment: How big are your Databases?

Comment: @Smartis They are between 2-5 mb.

Comment: Several things to check: 1. Use ProcessMonitor or ProcessExplorer to check that it is actually your application accessing the MDB file. (Maybe someone else keeps a lock on it) 2. Check whether you maybe have several instances of `DataBaseAccess` that refer to the same directory.

Comment: @NineBerry Checked and confirmed. 1. I used process monitor, only process using that file is mine. 2. I have only one DataBaseAccess instance per directory.

Comment: Are you sure it's not temp.mdb that is locked? - might be worth using System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() instead to elininate this.  Also maybe worth disposing all DataTable, OleDbDataAdapter and OleDbCommand objects explicitly (or clearing all references and explicitly calling System.GC.Collect()) before the call to CompactDatabase to see if this changes the behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. temp.mdb is supposed to be output file. Exception says which file, and it's not temp. Disposing OleDbDataAdapter and OleDbCommand (using "Using" did the charm.) DataTable didn't need disposing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code in all the methods where you use `OleDbDataAdapter` and `OleDbCommand` make sure to use the using-Pattern on these objects. They can keep the mdb file open even though the actual connection is already disposed.

Methods that require modification seem to be `GetTable`, `SetTable` and `ValidTable`.

Comment: using "using" on OleDbDataAdapter and OleDbCommand worked. Thank you.